# Iced tea-2.3.4 installation script fails on executing

Tags: 12.04, icedtea

I downloaded icedtea-2.3.4   tar ball and extracted it on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop system.

While running install-sh (permission allowed to be executable) and clicking on Run in terminal gives nothing but  just a frame of terminal window for fraction of second.

I am unable to install latest icedtea-2.3.4 , which I compulsorily require because one of banking site needs it.

How to install icedtea-2.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

Change to that directory after extracting the tar then do as

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

execute those commands one by one.

Comment: optimight@optimight:~$ cd Downloads
optimight@optimight:~/Downloads$ cd icedtea-2.3.4
optimight@optimight:~/Downloads/icedtea-2.3.4$ sudo ./install-sh
[sudo] password for optimight: 
./install-sh: no input file specified.
Which fine name is to be given? How to write exactly?

Comment: ok , optimight@optimight:~/Downloads/icedtea-2.3.4$ there type "ls" and give the output in pastebin.com

Comment: I pasted the output as suggested by you at http://pastebin.com/PYqL8RTX

Comment: @Optimight did you try those commands ?